# Leaflet showing radius as drawing circle

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

I was asked to see if I could using leaflet draw a circle and as I'm drawing it show what the current expanding radius is. Either as a tooltip or write it to a page label. I noticed the circle option has a showRadius option but can you capture this value as your drawing the circle?

Kind of like the measure tool that uses the drawing plugin can show your distance as you move the mouse.

This way the user can see how big their circle is as they are drawing it.

Any ideas, examples, hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Leaflet.draw](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw) plugin does that.

Check out this [demo](http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/)

However, it shows radius only when you create a circle. Unfortunately, not when you edit it.

Comment: For some reason it now works in my app. I'm using a dev copy and it wasn't working before. Thanks for showing me it can be done.